# how to use extracted string properties when referencing object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a utility type to extract string keys from a type but when i go to use that on an object of the same type i can't get typescript to recognize the value as a string.

```
type StringPropertyOf<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never
}[keyof T]

function myFunction<T>(rowId: StringPropertyOf<T>) {
  const getRowId = (row: T): string => {
    return row[rowId] // <-- need to ensure row[rowId] is string
  }
}
```

How do i adjust the code so typescript knows `row[rowId]` is a `string`?

[Playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwArwPaXqA8gGYA8AKgHxQC8UA3gFBRNQDaA0lClANYQhaEopALoAuIe2FQIAD2ARkAEwDOUZQhSooAfigdxyCADcI8egF8WvfoJH16ssFjxRCAV2QBjYIizIoALYgAGIe3r7IZOQAFNgA7gCSiuJwSGiYOKYEJBQAlHSMUJ5+6lCoEMAASliJitRQsTXipLni6mlaVJQMzFDwFW7w-vEs8UlSAPQTUMQAtLNQhhB1wFjSyMqD0CNjilKIqu2aheYW9EA)

Fleshed out example:

```
function useRowSelect<T>(rowId: StringPropertyOf<T>) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<Record<string, boolean>>({})

  const getRowId = (row: T): string => {
    return row[rowId] // <-- need to ensure row[rowId] is string
  }

  return {
      select: (row: T) => setSelected({...selected, [getRowId(row)]: true}),
      deselect: (row: T) => setSelected({...selected, [getRowId(row)]: false}),
      toggle: (row: T) => setSelected({...selected, [getRowId(row)]: !selected[getRowId(row)}),
      isSelected: (row: T) => selected[getRowId(row)]
  }
}

type Person = {
  id: string
  name: string
  age: number
  active: boolean
}

const rows: Array<Person> = []

function Example() {
  const controls = useRowSelect<Person>('id')
  return (
    <table>
      <body>
        {rows.map((row) => (
          <tr key={row.id}>
            <td>
              <input type='checkbox' checked={controls.isSelected(row)} onChange={() => controls.toggle(row)} />
            </td>
            <td>{row.name}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </body>
    </table>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you show some examples of how are you calling the function? It's hard to modify the function without knowing if it breaks anything.

Comment: @TobiasS. yes! i just added to the original question

Comment: While the new implementation details help too, I was more expecting some examples on how you are **calling** the function. What do valid calls look like? And when should a call lead to a compiler error?

Comment: @TobiasS. ah totally misread that. I've updated my question again. I don't think it's relevant though. My issue is that i get a typescript error where i'm pointing to in the code comment

Comment: Would [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbBPom) answer your question? If so, I could write an answer. If not what am I missing?

Comment: No, because i'd like the argument to `useRowSelect` to be restricted to string value keys from a type. If i change your example to `useRowSelect('foobar')` then i don't get an error on that line specifically but when i use the return functions. I want the inference from the `Person` type

Comment: once i figure this out, i want to change it to accept a string property name or a function that returns a string based on a row: 

`type rowId<T> = StringPropertyOf<T> | (row: T) => string`

Valid calls will eventually be:
`useRowSelect<Person>('id')`
`useRowSelect((row: Person) => person.id)`